# Visual Studio: Sorting and Filtering Intellisense List

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, intellisense

Is it possible to set option that for example:

I have object Object1

After typeing a dot after it there are displayed all properties methods, event and so on

Object1.

These are in alphabetical order.

Is it possible to order it by tyoe for example only events or only Properties ?

I also have resharper
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as far as I know this is not possible. Such a feature has been requested but [postponed for future versions](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=114373&wa=wsignin1.0).

ReSharper has some interesting and helpful code completion features though, you might want to check this blog post:

> **[Code Completion with ReSharper](http://resharper.blogspot.com/2007/05/code-completion-with-resharper.html)**